# get every value with maximum count in a numpy array

Tags: numpy, count, max, mode

For example, I have the following array:

```
x = [1,2,3,3,4,5,6,6,7,8]
```

I need the following output:

```
y = [3,6]
```

So, it is similar to mode but can return more than one value if more than one value has the same maximum count. What is an efficient way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Are the values in `x` always integers?  What are typical values of `len(x)` and `max(x)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just use `np.unique` with`return_counts = True`

```
u, c = np.unique(x, return_counts = True)
y = u[c == c.max()]
```

Comment: Thanks, Actually I just figured this by myself before you posted the answer but lets leave it for others to see.

Answer (score 1):

If `x` contains only nonnegative integers, and if `max(x)` is not too big, you can use [`numpy.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html):

```
In [230]: x = [1,2,3,3,4,5,6,6,7,8]

In [231]: counts = np.bincount(x)

In [232]: np.where(counts == counts.max())[0]
Out[232]: array([3, 6])
```

The array `counts` will have length `max(x)+1`, so if `max(x)` is huge, you might not want to use this.

This method can be significantly faster than using `numpy.unique`.